# How do I set up an OAuth2RestTemplate with client credentials and automatic token refresh in spring-security-oauth 2.2.1.RELEASE

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, spring-security-oauth2, refresh-token

I am implementing a client that authenticates with OAuth2 against WSO2 and I have serious trouble refreshing the access token, getting 401 UNAUTHORIZED. While I have already found out, what the Spring OAuth2 code does, I do not know why its behavior was changed in 2.2.1.RELEASE and to me it seems plain wrong. Actually using 2.0.14.RELEASE works.

Before I am going to show to you, what I have done and what I have already found out, let me formulate my question:

How am I supposed to realize an OAuth2 client with automatic token refresh with client credentials instead of user credentials?

So here is, what I have implemented so far. The client configures an `OAuth2RestTemplate` with `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` with `isClientOnly` flag `true`, as there are no user sessions. The client session can successfully be established and an access token and a refresh token are set.

```
@Bean
protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails() {
        @Override
        public boolean isClientOnly() {
            return true;
        }               
    };
    List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>(2);
    scopes.add("write");
    scopes.add("read");
    resource.setScope(scopes);
    resource.setGrantType("password");
    resource.setAccessTokenUri(TOKEN_URL);
    resource.setClientId(MY_CLIENT_ID);
    resource.setClientSecret(MY_CLIENT_SECRET);
    resource.setUsername(MY_SERVICE_USER);
    resource.setPassword(MY_SERVICE_USER_PW);
    return resource;
}


@Bean
public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {
    AccessTokenRequest atr = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplateWithBasicAuth(resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(atr));
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
    interceptors.add(new LoggingRequestInterceptor());      
    template.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    template.setRetryBadAccessTokens(true);
    return template;
}
```

So far so good. I have verified that this basically works.

But as soon as the access token expires I frequently run into 401 errors, because the token refresh is not executed. Instead, an ordinary authentication request is carried out, but using the client key and secret instead of user/password. To cut a long story short, I have debugged my way through spring-security-oauth2 into `AccessTokenProviderChain#obtainAccessToken` and found out, that whether a token refresh request is executed is decided upon in the following bit of code. [See on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/4c43f56a6d9f9735f2b0d8b73243c573cf8b3888/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/AccessTokenProviderChain.java#L96)

```
    if (resource.isClientOnly() || (auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated())) {   // P1
        existingToken = request.getExistingToken();
        if (existingToken == null && clientTokenServices != null) {
            existingToken = clientTokenServices.getAccessToken(resource, auth);
        }

        if (existingToken != null) {
            if (existingToken.isExpired()) {
                if (clientTokenServices != null) {
                    clientTokenServices.removeAccessToken(resource, auth);
                }
                OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = existingToken.getRefreshToken();
                if (refreshToken != null && !resource.isClientOnly()) {  // P2
                    accessToken = refreshAccessToken(resource, refreshToken, request);
                }
            }
            else {
                accessToken = existingToken;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see at P1, the block is entered if either an authorized user session exists (`auth`) or the resource is configured as `clientOnly`. As I do not have users but I am in a linked service scenario, I have `isClientOnly() == true && auth == null`. But at P2 the final decision upon actually doing the refresh is contraticted by requiring `!isClientOnly()`. So this effectively bans refresh requests in client only scenarios.

This was the way to go in versions before 2.2.1 and I have found out, that this seems to be a fix to the following [Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/pull/1128). To me this seems plain wrong.

Furthermore, to me the patch appears to break client functionality to fix an actual server misbehavior. As you can see in the issue discussion, I have already commented the there. But as that issue is closed and the spring-security-oauth2 forum states that discussions should be held here on StackOverflow, I am asking for help here.

Again the question: How should a client application be configured to consume OAuth2 secured services via OAuth2RestTemplate and an access token runtime of an hour and refresh token runtime of lets say two hours.

Comment: I changed the title into a question to conform with the StackOverflow format. Sorry for not getting that right, immediately.

Comment: First responses on other channels indicate, that the problem is using the user session dedicated grant type "password" instead of the grant type "client_credentials". The latter should be used for service-to-service-authentication and would not use token refresh at all, but would always re-login. This would explain the change in V2.2.1.RELEASE.

But in my scenario, the authentication server is not configured for providing access via client_credentials and for now I cannot change that. So unfortunately I still have to setup the connection using the "password" grant.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Minisha: I explicitly had to stick to the old spring-security-oauth2:2.0.14.RELEASE in that project. In new projects since then I've gotten rid of Spring alltogether and base on Scala with akka-http or dispatch-http. The solutions are much more flexible and transparent (and faster by the way).